# How can i prevent overlapping of DIV using CSS on screen resize?

Tags: css, html

DIVs are overlapping when i resize page to smaller size. I tried to search but could not find a suitable solution.

```
    <div class="column left">

      </div>

      <div class="column Middle">

      </div>

      <div class="column right">

      </div>


.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;

   /*  height:  */
}

.left {
  width: 16%;  
}

.right {
  width: 20%;  
}

.middle {
  position: relative;   
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;

}

.row h2 {

    color: #800000; 
}


.row:after {

    display: table;
    clear: both;
    height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.column {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    float: left;

}
```

DIVs are not overlapping when i am using overflow: auto in CSS.
overflow auto brings scroll bar which i do not like.

Can you please advise best possible solution?

Comment: have you tried with max-width: 100%;?

Comment: Yes i tried with max-width: 100%;and max-height: 100%;

Comment: please share more code. when i change it to max-width: 100% and resize the browser the scroll did disappear.

Comment: I added some more detail of code.

Comment: Other css rules are not addind new rules or overriding existing rules on your column div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated your code and the columns do overlap when it hits the 500px breakpoint. I had to amend though your middle class in the HTML as it was capitalized and wasn't getting the CSS styles. I'm not sure if that solves your problem?

```
     <div class="column left">
     </div>
     <div class="column middle">
     </div>
     <div class="column right">
     </div>

.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    position: relative;

   /*  height:  */
  }

  .left {
    width: 16%; 
    background: blue;
  }

  .right {
    width: 20%; 
    background: red;
  }

  .middle {
    position: relative;   
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    background: black;
  }

  .row h2 {

      color: #800000; 
  }


  .row:after {

      display: table;
      clear: both;
      height: 100%;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .column {
      padding: 5px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      overflow: visible;
      float: left;

  }
```

https://codepen.io/Angel-SG/pen/dwMvxN

Comment: by adding    min-height: 300px; in .column class helped me to get the desired output.Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

It seem that the padding:5px is causing it. When i change the width to 100% - 10px (5px padding from both sides) the scroll disappears.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  body { margin: 0;}
  .column {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: when i use overflow: auto; it is ok but there is a scroll bar which i do not like.

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior. Tried to add strings and no scroll-x appear. Maybe something else causing it?